# Create an indicator column to action other functions in corresponding rows

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create an indicator column (call it Column A) that I would use to action several functions such as a copy and paste, ClearContents, in other Columns (E,F,Q,R) in VBA.

Theoretically, I would place an 'x' or a '1' in column A which my code would read and then action my other commands.  So if there were an x in Column A, Row 14, then my code would copy/paste from (Q,14) to (E,14) for example.

The purpose of this request is to make my code more dynamic, where it is very static such as the example below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A9").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Range("E9:E10").Value = Range("I9:I10").Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to use the button or would you prefer for your 'actions' to kick in when you type the indicators into column A?

Comment: First, thank you for your fantastic answer.  I would like to use the Command Button if possible - how would that change the code?

Comment: One additional caveat.  Some of the cells that I copy from will then need to be cleared.  Further explanation: I am creating an inventory balance sheet, and so the "Month Ending Inventory" will be copied into the "Month Beginning Inventory" and then I would like to clear the data from the "Month Ending Inveno

Comment: Simple enough to add that. For example, in my macro for Case 1, if you wanted to clear `Q` after the copy, just add a line of code to do it underneath the copy... like this: `Range"q" & n).ClearContents`

Comment: My answer is giving you a framework to accomplish what you described... a more dynamic way to implement your actions. Exactly what those actions are is up to you. Just define them within the Select Case statement.

Comment: Would this change if I wanted to use a command button and pre-enter my indicator into Column A?

Comment: Please see my UPDATE at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Did the update work for you?

Comment: Close - I am getting an expected array error with the 'Command Button' update, but I'm not sure which part of code I'm missing.  Assuming it is something I will manually have to code.

Comment: Which line is that error happening on?

Comment: If Len(v(i, 1)) Then

Comment: Are your indicators going into column A? The only way you can get that error on that line is if column A is totally blank.

Comment: Indicators are in column A, using 1 as the indicator.  Do I need to give column A a specific name?

Comment: No name required. But you are getting the error when clicking the button AND there are indicators in column A?

Comment: That error has been corrected; now I'm erroring at the Public sub code line:
v = [a1].Resize(n)

Comment: "Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: I have a couple of minutes... If you'd like to send me the workbook, I'm sure I can fix this quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes you want the 'actions' to happen when you enter the indicators into column A.

For this example, '1' is an indicator of Copy and '2' is and indicator of ClearContents.

Place this procedure in the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        CustomActions
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And place this procedure in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub CustomActions(Target As Range)
    Dim n&
    Const INDICATOR_COL = 1
    If Target.Column <> INDICATOR_COL Then Exit Sub
    n = Target.Row
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case 1
            'copy Q to E
            Range("e" & n) = Range("q" & n)
        Case 2
            'clear Q and R
            Range("q" & n, "r" & n).ClearContents
    End Select
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

To use a command button to process column A indicators in batch mode do not use the Worksheet_Change() procedure from my original answer.

Instead use this event procedure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i&, n&, v
    n = [index(a:a,1+max(iferror(match({"*";9E+99},a:a,{-1;1}),1)))].Row
    v = [a1].Resize(n)
    For i = 1 To n
        If Len(v(i, 1)) Then
            CustomActions Range("a" & i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```